# MAC Address not changing after writing to Base Address Register 0

Tags: intel, mac-address, pci-e, base-address

I have a problem and I honestly have no idea where the problem is. I use an Intel Ethernet Controller and my objective is to change the MAC Address of that Controller.

What I allready did is mapping the BAR0 to virtual address space and changing the MAC Address there. After rebooting the value is still in BAR0 so it has successfully been written to the device. However when I check my MAC address with

```
ip link
```

I still get the old MAC address.

Does this have something to do with the prefetchable bit? I don't want to edit anything without being certain I won't "kill" the device or anything like that.

I hope someone can help me. Best reagards!

Comment: I am not sure which model you're talking about. [OSDev.org on i217](http://wiki.osdev.org/Intel_Ethernet_i217#Card_Addresses_and_Data_Structures) reveals that "The first thing you will need to do after detecting the BAR0 type and the existence of the EEPROM is to read the hardware MAC address of the NIC. The following method reads the hardware mac address based. If an EEPROM exists it will read it from the EEPROM else it will read it from address 0x5400 where it should be located in that case. It is very important to detect if an EEPROM exists or not prior to reading the MAC address. "

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I use the i210.
I am not sure what you mean with BAR0 type though. Do you mean "Region type" Memory / IO?

Comment: The regular Linux drivers can use an alternate MAC address; you don't *need* to hack this up yourself.  `ifconfig hw ether XX:YY:ZZ:...` should work, including getting the HW to respond to ARP requests for the MAC address and so on.  Still, upvoted because finding out how to program it yourself seems interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The problem was I needed to address the flash ob the network controller instead of its content directly. After that performing a flash cycle changes the MAC address.